Correctness of proof $(L={ww m \element {0,1}*) is irregular.
Let L be regular
Choose pumpinglength $n = |w|$
from  $|uv| \leq n$ and $v \geq 1$ follows
$|u| = \alpha$ $v =\beta$, $w= 2|w| - (\alpha+\beta)$ where $\alpha + \beta = n$.
For all $m \geq 0$ must follow $uv^mw \in L$
$uv^mw = \beta^m - \beta + 2 |w| \geq 2|w|$ for $m=2$
